# Flutter: How to check if stream is empty or has no events?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I'm using `flutter_beacon` package to scan for the beacons like this,

```
 _streamRanging =
            flutterBeacon.ranging(regions).listen((RangingResult result) {
              if (result.beacons.isEmpty) {
                _streamRanging.cancel();
                onBleSearch(false);
              }
              //do something else
            }
            );
```

now as there are no beacons found I want to call `onBleSearch(false)`, but it doesn't go inside the function of `.listen((l){})` because I think there are no events to call that function

so how I can check if the stream has no data and call this `onBleSearch(false)` function?

Comment: `Stream` has `isEmpty` property but it will not be helpful to you since if you use it you cannot call `listen` anymore

Comment: so its better to use for example `Stream.toList` method and check if its empty or not

Comment: You could add a `onDone` method on your `listen` and make a boolean to check if it has been called right away?

Comment: you can use `defaultIfEmpty(defaultValue)` or `switchIfEmpty(Stream)`

Comment: @pskink `Stream.toList` *When this stream ends, the returned future is completed with that list*. It is not relevant to real-time streaming check.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to check if the Stream is empty, but be aware that a Stream provides a way to receive a sequence of events. The Stream can be "empty" for an instance, and could possibly hold a value in the next. What you can do here is to continuously listen for events in the Stream and trigger the method depending on your use case.

```dart
StreamController.stream.listen(
  (event) => print('Value: $event'), // Check if empty
);
```

Another way is by checking if the List from the Stream has value by using [Stream.toList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/toList.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this the `.isEmpy` to check if a stream is connected

```dart
Stream<String>? myStream;



Future<void> checkStream() async {
    bool empty = await myStream.isEmpty;
    if (empty) {
      restart();
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```